# Execution of PreparedStatement select fails

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to select a record from a table `IsSELECTED`, using preparedStatements. My table has 3 fields (date (DATETIME), morning(BOOL), noon(BOOL), night(BOOL)) and one record with theses values (2013-12-12, 0 , 0, 0). My method tries to select the record with the given date.

```
     public void getTodayInfo(HttpSession session, String date) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    System.out.println("flag1"); 
    String sq = "SELECT date, morning, noon, night FROM IsSELECTED WHERE date='?'";

    try {       
        System.out.println("flag2");
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);            
        stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
        stm.setString(1, date);            
        System.out.println("flag3");
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sq);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("flag4");
            Shift s = new Shift(rs.getString(date), rs.getBoolean("morning"), rs.getBoolean("noon"), rs.getBoolean("night"));
            System.out.println("flag5" + s.toString());
            session.setAttribute("shiftsToday", s);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (stm != null)
            stm.close();
        if (c != null)
    c.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Goodbye!");

}
```

and nothing happens. I put some `System.out.println` to see where I have the problem and i get this

```
flag1 
flag2
```

Let's assume that it doesn't match with any record (but i see my table with this record, anyway) why the `flag3` isn't printed?

Comment: Change `SQLException` to `Exception` and see what happens. U sure that no exception is thrown? Is `Goodbye` printed out?

Comment: date=trunc(?); Also you must use rs.getDate if your column is of type Date.

Comment: I suppose it should be `getString("date")`

Comment: Can you please stop tagging JDBC questions with [servlets] instead of [jdbc]? This is not the first time you made this epic mistake. As a design hint, you should move all that JDBC code outside the servlet class into a reusable DAO class which you in turn can easily test using a Java application class with `main()` method and ultimately just import/call in your servlet class.

Comment: Ok, I will have in mind that.. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `'` present around `?` from your query.

```
String sq = "SELECT date, morning, noon, night FROM IsSELECTED WHERE date=?";
```

No need to pass query again while executing.

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

Also include `"` around date in `rs.getString(date)`

```
Shift s = new Shift(rs.getString("date"), rs.getBoolean("morning"), rs.getBoolean("noon"), rs.getBoolean("night"));
```

**Note:** if date is date field in database then you should use setDate, getDate method.

Comment: Passing the query to `executeQuery` in a `PreparedStatement` should trigger an `SQLException` (see the API doc).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to include `'` around the `?`, use just `date = ?`.

Also use:

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

instead of

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sq);
```

Comment: then i get this log message `flag1 
flag2
flag3
not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
Goodbye!`

Comment: Why is date a String?  Don't you want to setDate?  This isn't well written code.  You'd get more information out of the system if you printed the stack trace in the catch block.  Table and column names that are SQL keywords (e.g. 'date') are asking for trouble.  Try renaming to "shiftDate".

Comment: If you want to pass date as String, you must convert it using to_date functon of SQL, types must be the same!

Comment: ok! I am little confused about it.. i will read about it to clear these things.